# how to access multiple php files in different sub-folders under LAMPP in LINUX

Tags: php, linux, phpmyadmin, xampp, lampp

Hi I am new to LINUX and recently installed LINUXFX which was working great. Now I have LAMPP (XAMPP) Configuration issue with it. After installing XAMPP I was able to load XAMPP demo page successfully, but if I want to open my project folders which are located in different sub-directories,  I can't.

In detail, I have copied my project folders to /LAMPP/HTDOCS/ and in .CONF File I could be able to change the root path to access only one project folder. How can I make it for multiple projects. Please Help!

```
if($row){
   if($row['role']==0 || $row['role']=='0'){
    $_SESSION['login']=$Cashier;
    echo'<script>location.href="admin_dashboard.php";</script>'; 
    }elseif($row['role']==1 || $row['role']=='1'){
        $_SESSION['login']=$Cashier;
    echo'<script>location.href="cashier_dashboard.php";</script>';
  }else{
    echo'<script>alert("!This username  "); 
location.href="index.php";</script>';
    }
}else{
echo'<script>alert("!This username and password do not match "); 
location.href="index.php";</script>';
  }

}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: You probably want to add separate _virtual hosts_ for your projects.

Comment: @CBroe no, actually I have 3 to 4 projects on which I am working simultaneously. Hence I want to access any of these folders and run PHP!

Comment: Separate virtual hosts do not stop you from working on these projects simultaneously. They do allow for a proper separation of different projects though. And easy setting of the _proper_ document root for each.

Comment: @CBroe Hi, yes, I am able to work on the index.php in the direct folder, but unable to go the routed php file mentioned in the index.php file, please help!

Comment: Not sure what you mean there.

Comment: @CBroe, I have updated my code, plz chk the post. In the index.php after successful login I have asked to go to cashier_dashboard.php but in the browser it is giving error

Comment: What error - 404? Well if the file is in a sub-folder, then you need to include that sub-folder in the URL.

Comment: @Cbroe,  yes its 404, and I tried to set the root path in the browser itself, but not getting, is there any other way to include these sub-folders in LINUX - LAMPP?

Comment: _“and I tried to set the root path in the browser itself”_ - what does that _mean_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem as mentioned below.
First as suggested by @Cbroe, I set the path in the Apache Config file. The issue is with the file name. The file name was given as "cashier_dashboard.php" in the code and the original file name was "Cashier_Dashboard.php". As earlier while doing the same in windows 10, it was accepting the code without any problem. I presume in LINUX, we must be very careful in assigning the file name and this should be same in the PHP code as well!

Thank you @cbroe for guiding me!